# iOS - how to let a view both respond a touch and let it pass through it

Tags: ios, events, uiview, uikit, touch

I'd like to have my UIWebView respond to touch event from user, and also let views from behind respond to touch. Is it possible?

basically, i'd like to have my UIWebView interact with a touch but not "swallowing" it, and let it go through for another lower view too.

Comment: it just may be possible. i can try but only if you provide a conceptual example because the limitations of it will be dependent on **1**.What's on the UIWebView? **2**.What type of view is below it? **3**.What kind of objects are on the lower view? **4**.What kind of touches are you trying to record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, I believe, is no.

The best that you could do is to capture the touches in the `UIWebView` using one or more `UIGestureRecognizer`s and then manually manipulate or trigger actions in the lower `UIView`s.

Comment: the problem is my lower View is handled by Unity3D :D, i tried to use a subclass with overrode hitTest for capture default interaction only in some rectangle and let user touch the base view, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if an only if your webview is made by you. It will be done in PHP code for that site ie. when you tap on any button or any event is detected on your webview, then a parameter can be passed by PHP code from server in form of hidden field. You can recieve this by following code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",html);

    NSString *hdnPaymentStatusId = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('yourParametrer1').value"];
    NSLog(@"value%@",hdnPaymentStatusId);

    if ([hdnPaymentStatusId integerValue] == 1)
    {
        DWMyOrdersViewController *myOrderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DWMyOrdersViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myOrderVC animated:YES];
    }

    NSString *hdnCancelStatusId = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('yourParametrer2').value"];
    NSLog(@"value%@",hdnCancelStatusId);

    if ([hdnCancelStatusId integerValue] == 1)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }


}
```

Comment: i think you dont undersant my problem., i need to interact with two view with the same size at the same location with only one touch.